# Keras Image Data Generator Invalid File Name(s) Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am doing image augmentation. I have 3662 images belonged to 5 classes. Here is my image data generator.

```
train_data_generator = idg.flow_from_dataframe(train_data, directory = train_image_dir,
                    x_col = "id_code", y_col = "diagnosis",
                    class_mode = "categorical", shuffle = False, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size = 64, classes = ['No DR', 'Mild', 'Moderate', 'Severe', 'Proliferative DR'])
```

I check if the images can be read correctly. The below code snippet shows that images are correct and readable.

```
for i in range(0, len(train_data['id_code'])):
  file_id=train_data['id_code'].iloc[i]
  sdir="retinopathy_train"
  file_path=os.path.join(sdir, file_id) # should be full path to the image file
  try:
      image=cv2.imread(file_path)

  except:
      print('Invalid image file   '+ train_data['id_code'])
```

However image data generator says

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py:282: UserWarning: Found 5 invalid image filename(s) in x_col="id_code". These filename(s) will be ignored. .format(n_invalid, x_col)
```

Do you have any suggestions? If there are 5 invalid images, 3652+5=3657 So where are the last 5 images? Also I work on Google Colab, images are stored at Drive. I can check there are 3662 images in folder.

```
import os
len(os.listdir(train_image_dir))
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously an invalid data problem. I checked the excel file now everything works fine.